# Codeigniter Recursive function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a account section with below mentiond stucture

```
Assets
     Group
       Accountname
     Group
       Group
         accountname
         Group
           accountname
           accountname
           Group
            account
Etc....
```

User can create many accounts and groups under each group.
i have maintain database like,

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_account_details` (
`account_details_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `account_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `IsGroup` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0:not group,1:group',
  `Parent` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'parent id-account details id',
  `account_group_level` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '1:main group ,0:subgorup',
  `sub_group_level` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0:main group,1:sub group',
  `SystemAccount` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'system genarated not delete',
  `Level` float NOT NULL COMMENT 'level group Eg:1,1.1,1.1.1',
  `narration` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;
```

and datas like this

```
    (1, '1000', 'Asset', 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 'system generated', 1),
(2, '2001', 'Liability', 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 'system generated', 1),
(3, '3001', 'Income', 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 'system generated', 1),
(4, '4001', 'Expence', 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 'system generated', 1),
(5, '1002', 'Calendar', 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 'assets subaccount', 1),
(6, '1003', 'Contacts', 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 'assets sub account', 1),
(7, '2002', 'Textbook', 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 'liability sub account', 1),
(8, '2003', 'Pencil', 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 'liability sub account', 1),
(9, '2004', 'Notebook', 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 'liability sub account', 1),
(10, '2006', 'bench', 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 'liability sub account', 1),
(11, '3002', 'Stamp', 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 'income sub account', 1),
(12, '3003', 'student fee', 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 'income sub group', 1),
(13, '3004', 'Tution fee', 0, 12, 0, 1, 0, 1.1, 'income sub group sub account', 1),
(14, '3009', 'bus fee', 1, 12, 0, 1, 0, 1.2, 'income Group-sub account', 1),
(15, '3010', 'Hostel fee', 0, 12, 0, 1, 0, 1.3, 'income group-sub account', 1),
(16, '3012', 'mess fee', 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 'income sub account', 1),
(17, '4002', 'Note Book', 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 'expence sub group', 1),
(18, '4003', 'Vehicle parts', 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 'expence account', 1),
(19, '4007', 'paint', 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 3, 'expence sub account', 1),
(20, '300942', 'tyre fee', 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 1.2, 'fsdfs', 1);
```

a demoimage like this [account group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSP6D.png)

i am trying with

```
public function grouP_Data() {
        $this->db->select("account_details_id,account_code,account_name,IsGroup,Level");
        $this->db->from("tbl_account_details");
        $this->db->where("status", 1);
        $this->db->where("Level", 0);
        $this->db->where("IsGroup", 1);
        $qur = $this->db->get();
        if ($qur->num_rows() > 0) {
            $this->resul = $qur->result_array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->resul); $i++) {
                if (!empty($this->resul[$i]["account_details_id"])) {
                    $this->aa = $i;
                    $this->Get_Tree_parent($i, $this->resul[$i]["account_details_id"]);
                }
            }
            return $this->resul;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function Get_Tree_parent($a, $parent) {
        $this->db->select("account_details_id,Parent,account_code,account_name,IsGroup,Level");
        $this->db->from("tbl_account_details");
        $this->db->where("status", 1);
        $this->db->where("Parent", $parent);

        $qure = $this->db->get();
        if ($qure->num_rows() > 0) {
            $res = $qure->result_array();
            if ($this->aa >= 0 && $this->jj == "") {
                $this->resul[$this->aa]["details"] = $res;
            } elseif ($this->aa >= 0 && $this->jj >= 0) {
                $this->resul[$this->aa]["details"][$this->jj]["subdetails"] = $res;
            }
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($res); $j++) {
                if ($res[$j]["IsGroup"] == "1") {
                    $this->jj = $j;
                    $this->Get_Tree_parent($this->aa, $res[$j]["account_details_id"]);
                } else {
                    $this->jj = "";
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

result is like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [account_details_id] => 1
            [account_code] => 1000
            [account_name] => Asset
            [IsGroup] => 1
            [Level] => 0
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 5
                            [Parent] => 1
                            [account_code] => 1002
                            [account_name] => Calendar
                            [IsGroup] => 0
                            [Level] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 6
                            [Parent] => 1
                            [account_code] => 1003
                            [account_name] => Contacts
                            [IsGroup] => 0
                            [Level] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [account_details_id] => 2
            [account_code] => 2001
            [account_name] => Liability
            [IsGroup] => 1
            [Level] => 0
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 7
                            [Parent] => 2
                            [account_code] => 2002
                            [account_name] => Textbook
                            [IsGroup] => 0
                            [Level] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 8
                            [Parent] => 2
                            [account_code] => 2003
                            [account_name] => Pencil
                            [IsGroup] => 0
                            [Level] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 9
                            [Parent] => 2
                            [account_code] => 2004
                            [account_name] => Notebook
                            [IsGroup] => 0
                            [Level] => 3
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 10
                            [Parent] => 2
                            [account_code] => 2006
                            [account_name] => bench
                            [IsGroup] => 0
                            [Level] => 4
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [account_details_id] => 3
            [account_code] => 3001
            [account_name] => Income
            [IsGroup] => 1
            [Level] => 0
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 11
                            [Parent] => 3
                            [account_code] => 3002
                            [account_name] => Stamp
                            [IsGroup] => 0
                            [Level] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 12
                            [Parent] => 3
                            [account_code] => 3003
                            [account_name] => student fee
                            [IsGroup] => 1
                            [Level] => 1
                            [subdetails] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [account_details_id] => 20
                                            [Parent] => 14
                                            [account_code] => 300942
                                            [account_name] => tyre fee
                                            [IsGroup] => 0
                                            [Level] => 1.2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 16
                            [Parent] => 3
                            [account_code] => 3012
                            [account_name] => mess fee
                            [IsGroup] => 0
                            [Level] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [account_details_id] => 4
            [account_code] => 4001
            [account_name] => Expence
            [IsGroup] => 1
            [Level] => 0
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 17
                            [Parent] => 4
                            [account_code] => 4002
                            [account_name] => Note Book
                            [IsGroup] => 0
                            [Level] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 18
                            [Parent] => 4
                            [account_code] => 4003
                            [account_name] => Vehicle parts
                            [IsGroup] => 0
                            [Level] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [account_details_id] => 19
                            [Parent] => 4
                            [account_code] => 4007
                            [account_name] => paint
                            [IsGroup] => 0
                            [Level] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

under income array  more datas and sub groups not display in this method.how to solve this?